# What notation is used in the styled-components documentation?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

In the documentation of styled-components you commonly see the following notation used in examples

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred
`;

render(
    <Button>Click me</Button>
);
```

JSX being passed as a parameter to `render` really threw me off when I was starting to learn styled-components. Is this some kind of alternative notation in React, that I somehow missed? Is it meant as pseudo code shorthand for the return value of React's render function? Is it some kind of DSL that can be used with styled-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styled-components web page uses [React Live](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-live) to render demo components, so *that* `render()` is a specific imperative form enabled by React Live and is not directly related with styled-components.

That being said, there's nothing special in passing JSX to a `render()` function: you usually do that with `ReactDOM.render()`. JSX compiles into `React.createElement()`, so what you're actually passing to the function is a React element.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was thinking in components and didn't make the mental connection to `ReactDOM.render()`. Everything makes sense now.